# Is vue.config.js file executed on building or starting the Vue App?

Tags: vue.js

I am using `vue.config.js` to inject configuration on App start.
It works on my dev machine, when I execute a `vue-cli-service serve` command.
As stated in docs, this command "starts a dev server".

I thought when my App is run inside a Docker pod, it would launch a similar command, but obviously, it is not the case because my configuration is not loaded.

So I may misunderstand the step where this file is used: building or starting?

Comment: The `vue.config.js` file is used both when serving the application in development mode on a development server (`vue-cli-service serve`) and also when building (running `vue-cli-service build`).  Building compiles (not sure if this is the right word really) your Vue files, TypeScript, CSS preprocessors, etc and creates a dist folder with files ready for a production server (such as IIS). The dist folder contains static files such as .js, .css and .html files.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: There are object configurations for dev and build inside vue.config.js. It's worth checking if the configuration you are looking for is only for dev server, because it won't be applied in production if it is the case

Comment: @BernardBorg, @IgorMoraru, thanks for your responses. I understand they lead towards `vue.config.js` is used only during app build.

Comment: No, `vue.config.js` is used for both building the codebase and serving the application.